# Jquery input type hidden value data toggle add/remove

Tags: jquery, html, input, duplicates, toggle

Basically i have two buttons that insert dynamic data to the one input value:

```
    <button class="sunday">Sunday</button>
    <button class="monday">Monday</button>

    <input type="hidden" value="3/15/2017, 3/16/2017, 3/17/2017">
```

Each button inserts 3 dates, so if you click both on sunday and monday for example you will get

```
<input type="hidden" value="3/15/2017, 3/16/2017, 3/17/2017, 3/18/2017, 3/19/2017, 3/20/2017">
```

What would be the best way to do this with JQuery but to be like a toggle, I want to add them but not to duplicate them.

Comment: What date should inserted when `.sunday` is clicked?

Comment: Why not use checkboxes?

Comment: its dynamic, each button inserts 3 dates, for example each day the dates will be different

Comment: @nfn neil I can't use checkboxes

Comment: Where is dates of buttons? In attribute or in variable?

Comment: I get them from objects data, the code is to big and complicated thats why i tried to make it simple here. I Am trying to understand the logic to just toggle the data somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I looked at the code listed and based on the comments, I think this would be the a way of doing it.  To set the dates for each the checkboxes,  simply modify the `hiddenDates` attribute.

```js
$(".checks button").click(function () {
  $(this).data("checked",true);
 newDates = [];
 $(".checks button").each(function () {
  if ($(this).data("checked"))
   newDates.push($(this).attr("hiddenDates"));
 });
 $("#hiddenArea").val(newDates.join(", "));
 console.log($("#hiddenArea").val());
});
$(".checks input:first").trigger("change");
```

```css
label {
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checks">
  <button hiddenDates="3/15/2017, 3/16/2017">Sunday</button>
  <button hiddenDates="4/15/2017">Monday</button>
</div>

<input id="hiddenArea" type="hidden" value="" />
```

Comment: This works great, exactly as I wanted, but I need it with buttons and I get the logic, probably I will make something out of it because this was the confusing part, thanks...

Comment: I updated the code.  Go ahead and check it out.  Please remember to mark as solution if you liked it, it helps a lot.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".sunday, .monday").off("click").on("click",function(){
    var existing = [];
    var duplicates = $('#ElementID').filter(function() {
        var value = $(this).val().split(",");
        //compare the array and insert to existing array
        existing.push(value);
    });
    ("#hidden").value(existing);
});
```